# How to get specific value from command from ps aux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Running ps aux gives something along the lines of:

```
    user 2222 0.0 0.0 24235 346323 ? s Apr08 0:00 /command value=4
```

In this case, I'm trying to capture the value of 'value'. I've tried

```
    grep 'value' | ps aux | awk '{print $11}'
```

without success. Can anyone help out?

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Can you tell us what you're *really* trying to do, and perhaps we can suggest a better way to get where you want to go?

Comment: @ghoti this is exactly what I'm trying to do, just grab the number value in a command after running ps aux

Comment: perhaps you can look at only pgrep

Comment: @naesmanak, I know it's what you're trying to do. It's your motivation that I'm questioning. You aren't just gathering this value for kicks. Are you really interested in the *value*? If so, what's the program, and how might we have it store the value in a better place than the process table? Is this part of a monitoring system? If so, what does the value represent, and can we validates its *impact* in `/command` rather than just the fact that `/command` has been called with it as an argument? There's more to this than you've shared. Don't want to give you bad advice, even if you ask for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming GNU grep

```
pgrep -fl 'command.*value' | grep -oP 'value=\K\S+'
```

Answer (score 1):

run this command

```
ps aux |grep 'value' | awk '{print $12}'
```

remember when you pipe a command, the output goes from left to right.

Comment: of course, my mistake! Do you know how to just get the number, and omit "value="?

Comment: @naesmanak - `man grep` and look up `-o`. Or consider using sed. Or skip grep and awk entirely and just use sed. Or skip grep and sed entirely and just use awk.

Comment: D'Arcy, wouldn't it make more sense to grep for `/command`, then parse and return the value, or return an error if the value isn't found?  What if some other command is run with `value=something` in its options?